# Obtener id de un combo laravel

Tags: laravel, select, combobox

Estoy trabajando con LARAVEL 
Tengo un foreach que me carga materias de mi base de datos en una vista.
Necesito que al seleccionar una materia mandar su id a otra vista...

Lo que hace ahorita es que al seleccionar diferentes materias, me carga el mismo id, y ese id es de la última materia del foreach.

¿Alguien sabe como se hace esto?

Codigo:

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('idc_materia') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <select id="" class="form-control" name="">
      @foreach ($materiasxmaestro as $materiasxma)
      <option value="{{$materiasxma->idc_materia}}">
        {{$materiasxma->mat_nombre}}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
      @if ($errors->has('idc_materia'))
      <span class="help-block">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('idc_materia') }}</strong>
      </span>
      @endif
      <br/>
    </div>
    <a href="{{ route('k_calificacion.create', $materiasxma->idc_materia)}}"
       name="category"class="btn btn-info btn-md">Calificar grupo</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Sí manipula el `select` me temo que con `PHP` solo, no será posible hacerlo. tendría que hacerlo, quizá con un poco de código `JavaScript` .

Comment: Tienes que quitar la ruta de tu botón "calificar" y hacer el envió desde javascript/jquery/... haciendo un submit con el valor del select y el csrf_token (tendras que quitar el parametro de la url y ponerla tipo POST)

Answer (score 1):

Te faltaba el name="materia"

```
<select id="" class="form-control" name="materia">
  @foreach ($materiasxmaestro as $materiasxma)
  <option value="{{$materiasxma->idc_materia}}">{{$materiasxma->mat_nombre}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```